# New in dynamic memory. realloc ();

Tags: dynamic, realloc

I'm trying to study at the moment, but the file that was sent to me is not correct. I tried do fix a couple of things but it starts and right after that it crushes. I'm learning dynamic memory, so i don't know it. Here is the code for realloc ();

```
 #include <stdio.h> /* printf, scanf, NULL */

    #include <stdlib.h> /* malloc, free, rand */

    int main ()

{

 int count=0,i;

 int *stations=NULL,*ptrToStations=NULL;



for(i=1;i<=7;i++,count++)
    {

ptrToStations=(int*)realloc(stations,count*sizeof(int));

if(ptrToStations!=NULL)//заделили сме памет

 { stations = ptrToStations;

 ptrToStations[count]=i;}

    }

for(i=0;i<7;i++)

printf("%d",stations[i]);

printf("\n");



//добавяне на 8 елемент

ptrToStations=(int*)realloc(stations,++count*sizeof(int));

if(ptrToStations!=NULL)//заделили сме памет

 { stations = ptrToStations;

 ptrToStations [count-1]=count;}



 for(i=0;i<count;i++)

printf("%d",stations[i]);

printf("\n");

int x=3;

//преместваме елементите с един назад

for(i=x;i<count;i++)


ptrToStations[i-1]=ptrToStations[i];

//премахване на 8 елемент

ptrToStations=(int*)realloc(stations,--count*sizeof(int));

if(ptrToStations!=NULL)//заделили сме памет



 stations = ptrToStations;



for(i=0;i<count;i++)


printf("%d",stations[i]);

printf("\n");


 free (ptrToStations);

 free (stations);

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: Code comments should be in English

Answer (score 0):

You have had several problems here

1. double free of the same memory chunk in the end
2. count should start with 1. Overwise on the first iteration you try to change the size of memory block for 0 bytes
3. out of array bound error
   ptrToStations[count]=i;

Your code should actually look like this

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, scanf, NULL */

    #include <stdlib.h> /* malloc, free, rand */

    int main ()

{

 int count=1,i;

 int *stations=NULL,*ptrToStations=NULL;



for(i=1;i<=7;i++,count++){

    ptrToStations=(int*)realloc(stations,count*sizeof(int));

    if(ptrToStations != NULL) { 
        stations = ptrToStations;
        ptrToStations[count-1]=i;
        for(i=0;i<count;i++)
            printf("%d",stations[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}





//добавяне на 8 елемент

ptrToStations=(int*)realloc(stations,++count*sizeof(int));

if(ptrToStations!=NULL){ 
    stations = ptrToStations;
    ptrToStations [count-1]=count;
    }



 for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    printf("%d",stations[i]);
printf("\n");

int x=3;

//преместваме елементите с един назад

for(i=x;i<count;i++)
    ptrToStations[i-1]=ptrToStations[i];

//премахване на 8 елемент

ptrToStations=(int*)realloc(stations,--count*sizeof(int));

if(ptrToStations!=NULL) {
    stations = ptrToStations;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
        printf("%d",stations[i]);
printf("\n");
}


 free (stations);

 return 0;

}
```